# Linux Standard Base 3.1 must be installed

Tags: package-management

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 up to date. I am trying to run a script (the 64-bit Linux installer on this page: https://www2.ordbogen.com/downloads/#).

However, I am met with an error.

```
To run this installer, Linux Standard Base 3.1 must be installed.
The following LSB modules are not present in your system:

core-3.1-noarch
core-3.1-amd64
desktop-3.1-amd64

To install the missing modules, open a terminal and run the following command as root:

apt-get install lsb-desktop-amd64
```

The command they suggest is of course not working on my version of Ubuntu. I tried installing the package lsb, but this does not resolve the problem. I am out of ideas to solve this problem.

Thanks for your help!

SebGondron

Comment: That is a non English page so no help for users of this site. Does it say on there any place what versions of Ubuntu or another Linux it will work on?

Comment: LSB 3.1 was a 2005 standard which is years in the past. Current LSB is version 5.0 (June 2015) - https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml   The software you are trying to run must be ancient (are you sure you want to run it?  if it's not been updated in that long, how safe can it be?)

Comment: Maybe you should ask ordbogen.com what Ubuntu / Linux versions they support ... and how to get an updated current version of the installer.

Comment: I asked ordbogen.com and I am waiting for an answer. To be fair, I think this page is an artifact, since the current page for downloading their desktop program only mentions Windows and Mac versions.
I need that software unfortunately for an exam... But I was curious about the possibility to run a software that requires LSB 3.1 on a recent machine. One possibility that remains for me is to try an old Linux virtual machine (though I would probably want to avoid that for an exam).

I am aware of the potential security issues, I am trying for now to run it on a Ubuntu virtual machine :) .

Comment: As expected, they don't have any solutions for Linux and I don't think they really care for providing anything else than the Windows or Mac versions. Well, I guess my only hope is to try to run that software on a old Ubuntu in a virtual environment.